# How do I design a net throwing device for my gnomish character?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons

Keep in mind this is for the BBEG coming through a portal in a game I'm playing in. (We know a group is trying to summon it and are looking into backup plans if we can't stop them - and knowing my DM we might fail)

I have a gnome with a bit of an inventive streak. He wants to invent a catapult, or launcher of some sort designed to help "wrap up" a gargantuan to colossal enemy in a net with sharp blades, or shards of glass or other sticky damaging substance as it were to allow for easier attacking. Heck, it could even be launched with a weapon like a harpoon. "Tanglefoot" bags wouldn't help much with an enemy that scale. The devide doesn't have to be all that portable, just provided it can be wheeled / hoisted to some location to be able to shoot the enemy from some distance away. It also needs to be able to be reloaded (even if it takes a whole round or 2 to do so).

Did anyone ever do this before, (even house rules would work) and if so what did they use to represent it? What did it cost? What was its range? it damage (if applicable)?

Comment: Are magic items or spells acceptable, or does this need to be a purely mundane device?

Comment: @Miniman being he's a gnomish inventor... he doesn't have the magical skill (other than minor magics all gnomes have). And it's not as if he has the time to be going on a quest to find something to suit the purpose (time's a ticking, a week or less [game time mind you]) and if they don't stop it, the BBEG will be summoned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- Your BBEG is *really* big, like Colossal or so. If he's smaller than that, targeting him with siege weapons simply won't be effective.
- You have access to artillery trained NPC's for both construction and deployment. Without them, the chance of successfully building the device drops considerably, and you're unlikely to get more than a single shot from it in the field.

An arbalest (siege-sized crossbow), a tube, and some kind of 'cup' for the arbalest to shoot up the tube, so the net doesn't get caught on the arbalest's bow string. mount the tube on top of the arbalest, feed the string through guide-slots in the side of the tube, then pack the cup and rolled up net down the tube like a cannon.

Given that you barely have a couple of days to construct and test the device (you'll need time to move and place it as well), it seems likely that your device would have a high chance of failure ranging from (best case) the net never unravels, flies through the air, bounces off the BBEG and is ignored, right up to (worst case) the net never unravels, flies through the air, bounces off the BBEG and he decides to come over and see what you've got there. Plenty of half-way options too, like the tube coming loose, or the tube cutting the string as you fire it and whipping heavy ropes through the crowd of siege artillerists and taking out your carefully selected NPC's.

The chances of reloading this thing are pretty much dependent on how lucky you get on the first shot. If it works, then great! The artillery crew can take a shot probably every 3-4 rounds. (I'm not sure if 3.5 has any particular rules for siege weapons. It's never come up in any of the games I've played, but then again, given the breadth of 3.5 I imagine they have to be in there somewhere.)

Comment: There's siege rules from pazio (which my DM will allow me to use) here: http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/combat/siegeEngines.html

Comment: Excellent. That covers the "how" then. Now it's simply a matter of actually modifying an arbalest in a suitable manner, and you'll be 100% ready for everything to backfire spectacularly! Er, I mean, I'm sure it will work out perfectly! -cough-

Answer (score 0):

If the portal is a fixed location, why not make a trap at that same location? 
Because.., have you ever seen the rules for shooting with a siege engine? And those don't even cover moving targets! A Ballista could work though (a Gnome getting a -6 size modifier on attack with those puppy's), is the BBEG any kind of whale by any chance?

EDIT: New idea. Does your DM allow (strong) magnetism? Getting the creature to swallow a strong magnet could serve you and your (now-homing-missile-)ballista a lot of good! Be sure to add some iron to whatever you're about to chuck at him, a big net reinforced with iron straps f.e. I hope this helps.

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, not discussion. Please take any discussion to [Role-playing Games Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=rpg.stackexchange.com). Prior discussion has been removed.